# How would I use calculus to prove $\arcsin x=\arctan(x/\sqrt{1-x^2})$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My question is how would I prove the following problem. Im not sure how I would begin.
$$\arcsin x=\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},|x|<1$$

Comment: This is (to some extent) related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254561/proof-of-arctanx-arcsinx-sqrt1x2

Answer (score 3):

A draw is also very good :-)

You can see that $\theta=\arcsin(x)$. But you also have that 
$$\tan\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies \theta=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$
what prove the claim. By the way, you can also deduce that 
$$\theta=\arccos(\sqrt{1-x^2})=\arcsin(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right).$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when trying to prove  function equalities in calculus,  you may follow the following procedure:

1. Define $f(x)$, so that what you are going to prove is $f(x)=0$. 5 sO in your case  let $f(x)  = \arcsin(x) - \arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})$ .
2. Compute $f'(x)$ and try to show $f'(x)=0$. Then your $f(x) $ is constant.  (and this is the case in your question)
3. Calculate $f(a)$ for some $a$ in the domain you have, to find that $f(a)=0$, and as  $f$ is constant, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in your domain. (in your case try  $f(0)$).

Comment: 3.) Is not very clear !  it's enough to find $f(a)$ and get $f(x)=f(a)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Surb yes, since you show in 2° that the derivative is zero, so your function is constant,  i.e. $ f(x)=c $ for some c constant, and thus $ f(a)=c $ also

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{d(\arctan x/\sqrt{1-x^2})}{dx}$$

$$=\dfrac1{1+x^2/(1-x^2)}\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\dfrac12\dfrac x{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}(-2x)\right)$$

$$=\dfrac{(1-x^2)(1-x^2+x^2)}{(1-x^2+x^2)(1-x^2)^{3/2}}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\arcsin (X)=\alpha$$ means simply that $$\sin \alpha=X$$ and $$\arctan (Y)=\alpha$$ means $$\tan \alpha=Y$$
so your equation means:
$$
\tan \alpha=\dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \alpha}}= \dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}
$$